# Loop through nested dictionary, replacing values with items from a list

Tags: python

I am working with a json file that I have now converted to a nested dictionary with the following structure:

```
dictionary = {
     '4123bf9f': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
     '45361a6c': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
     '4d521c71': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
     '5b00c155': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
     '875737f4': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
     '90a64c61': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''}
} etc
```

I am trying to loop through the nested dictionary and change the values for the keys, using items from a list.

For example:

```
topics = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5 ', '6']
```

When integrated would become:

```
dictionary = {
     '4123bf9f': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '1'},
     '45361a6c': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '2'},
     '4d521c71': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '3'},
     '5b00c155': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '4'},
     '875737f4': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '5'},
     '90a64c61': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'}
} etc
```

I have tried a few different approaches but each has resulted in the same output. I realised the code below is probably too simplistic an approach but for sake of clarity of my problem, the following code:

```
def update_dic(dictionary):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        dictionary[k].update({"topic": n for n in topics})
```

Results in this output

```
dictionary = {
     '4123bf9f': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'},
     '45361a6c': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'},
     '4d521c71': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'},
     '5b00c155': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'},
     '875737f4': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'},
     '90a64c61': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'}
} etc
```

Is it possible to loop through my nested dictionary, replacing "topic" with a distinct value from my list?
I have considered trying to make each page in my dictionary a class but was unsure if this was an appropriate method

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary comprehension is creating dictionary elements for every item in the list each time. But since you give them all the same key `topic`, only the last one is in the resulting dictionary. That's why you keep getting `"topic": 6`.

Use `zip()` to iterate through the dictionary keys and list elements in parallel, rather than nesting them. And there's no need to use `update()` if you're just setting one key of the dictionary, just assign to that key.

```
def update_dic(dictionary):
    for k, v in zip(dictionary, topics):
        dictionary[k]['topic'] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
topic = iter(topics)
for d in dictionary.values():
    d['topic'] = next(topic)
```

And another:

```
for d, d['topic'] in zip(dictionary.values(), topics):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {
 '4123bf9f': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
 '45361a6c': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
 '4d521c71': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
 '5b00c155': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
 '875737f4': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''},
 '90a64c61': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': ''}
}
topics = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5 ', '6']
topic=iter(topics)
for key in dictionary.keys():
     dictionary[key]['topic']=next(topic)
print(dictionary)
```

output:

```
 {'4123bf9f': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '1'}, '45361a6c': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '2'}, '4d521c71': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '3'}, '5b00c155': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '4'}, '875737f4': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '5 '}, '90a64c61': {'date': '', 'link': '', 'topic': '6'}}
```